# Button CSS from seemingly nowhere? How to left-align

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a button currently on a custom Angular component that looks to have some margin value coming from nowhere.

Here is an image of the button highlighted using the Dev Tools:

[image: SignInButton]

The small blue section on the left of the button is what I'd like to get rid of, or in other words, how can I left-align this button?

Here is the current CSS that is being applied to it:

[image: CSS]

Any ideas as to why this may be happening? This button is part of a form and it looks like there may be other styles being applied to it because of that (ng.untouched, ng.pristine, ng.invalid).

Thanks

Comment: Please post all relevant HTML and CSS, not just a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

`display:flex` and `aling-items: flex-end` must be applied to the container, not the items.